# How to Display result of subquery rows as one column in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, pivot

I have three tables Category, Movies and RelCatMov

**Category-table**

```
    categoryid, categoryName
1            thriller
2            supsense
3            romantic
4            action
5            sci-fi
```

**Movies-table**

```
movieid, movieName
1            Avataar
2            Titanic
3            NinjaAssassin
```

**RelCatMov-table**

```
categoryid, MovieID
1            1
2            2
3            2
4            2
5            2
```

Now i Want to display a the record as

```
MovieName     Categories
Titanic    Suspense,Romantic,Sci-fi,action
```

How to do this.

I am writing a query

```
select MovieName,(select categoryname from category b,relcatmov c where b.categoryid=c.categoryid and c.movieid=a.movieid) as categories from movies a;

Error: Subquery returns more than one row!!!
```

How to display the result of rows in one column?

Please help!!!

Comment: Why the specific(rather strange) requirement to get comma separated values? Not a nice way to represent a one to many mapping in RDBMS.

Comment: maybe for the same reason I needed it. To create optimized in memory rep for simple searches. Much faster and easier to do a text search of comma separated than use another connection or thread on the database.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Oracle it's called stragg. In MySQL it's GROUP_CONCAT.

```
select MovieName,(select GROUP_CONCAT(categoryname) from category b,relcatmov c where b.categoryid=c.categoryid and c.movieid=a.movieid) as categories from movies a;
```

For reference, your problem is that MySQL wants you to return a single value and you're returning several rows instead.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning "stragg" in your answer...this question came up first in a Google search for "mysql stragg".